# Room Migration didn't properly handle

Tags: android, android-room

Getting the following exception:

Expected:

> TableInfo{name='chat_table', columns={message=Column{name='message',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   messageStatus=Column{name='messageStatus', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}},
>   foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found:

> TableInfo{name='chat_table',
>   columns={messageStatus=Column{name='messageStatus', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false,
>   primaryKeyPosition=1}, message=Column{name='message', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[],
>   indices=[]}

Can anyone please suggest what is the issue here? I am simply copying table column values to another table. Then dropping the first table and then renaming the new table to old name.

```
 1. database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE chat_table_new (id INTEGER,
        messageStatus TEXT, message TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))")
 2. database.execSQL("INSERT INTO chat_table_new SELECT * FROM
        chat_table") 
 3. database.execSQL("DROP TABLE chat_table") 
 4. database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE chat_table_new RENAME TO chat_table")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
@Database(entities = {Student.class, BookIssue.class},version = 1)
public abstract class StudentDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static StudentDatabase studentDatabase;
public static StudentDatabase getStudentDatabase(Context context)
{
    if (studentDatabase==null)
    {
        studentDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),StudentDatabase.class,"student-database").addMigrations(StudentDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2).build();

    }

    return studentDatabase;
}

public abstract StudentDao studentDao();
public abstract BookDao bookDao();

public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 =new Migration(1,2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("alter table Student "+"add column pf String");
    }
};
}
```

more understanding refer this link
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929

Comment: Thanks for help. However, ALTER table is used to either add a column to DB or Rename table name. But however, to delete a column, or rename column name, we have to follow the approach mentioned above. Any idea on this?

Comment: you can perform MySql all query for database operation. First read about all database operation from mysql then perform operation into room db.